# Why does sssd query for all automountkeys when looking for a specific one?

Tags: centos7, sssd, autofs

I am attempting to convert `autofs` from using ldap maps to using sss maps.

However, it appears that `sssd` wishes to query for all automount keys rather than just the specific one it needs. This is causing the query to run afoul of the ldap server's size limits.

Is there a way to change this behavior in sssd?
I believe the filter should be `"(&(|(automountKey=$key)(automountKey=\2A))(objectClass=automount))"` rather than `"(&(automountKey=*)(objectClass=automount))"`

```
May 11 13:35:55 ldapserver slapd[12829]: conn=3518 op=7 SRCH base="automountMapName=auto.home,ou=auth-krb5p,ou=automount,dc=example,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(automountKey=*)(objectClass=automount))"
May 11 13:35:55 ldapserver slapd[12829]: conn=3518 op=7 SRCH attr=objectClass automountKey automountInformation
May 11 13:35:55 ldapserver slapd[12829]: conn=3518 op=7 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=4 nentries=500 text=
```